# How to generate code C Program from Pari/GP code?

Tags: c, gcc, pari

I'm a beginner in Pari/GP library. I want to generate C program from gp code. I followed the tutorial in http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/manuals/gp2c/gp2c.html. But I'm fetching some errors. Here I enter in gp program directory and try to run using following command.

```
$ gp2c-run squfof.gp gcc: error: ,--export-all-symbols: No such file or directory
```

Actually, I'm little bit confused with the tutorials. Can anyone guide me to run a Pari/GP program for polynomial multiplications (or any other simple operation) and its corresponding C program generating procedure?

Comment: Off the top o my mind: is `squfof.gp` reachable?

Comment: @LPs; Many thanks for your great support. The file squfof.gp is accessible definitely. Actually, c code is generated that I got when the directory now. But the getting the above error during running the command. May be I need to create a very simple gp file and then try again. I don't know how squfof.gp works till now.

Comment: Well, the error is very generic. May be caused by tons of things: missing library, no supported arch by installed library (such as 32bit vs 64bit). Try to create a very minimal code and compile it. Could be a good idea to post the code: someone can help you better.

Comment: see another tutorial : https://pl.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programowanie_w_systemie_UNIX/pari#przyk.C5.82ad